# Custom View using JSOM

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I am currently working on a custom JQUERY Code to export the SharePoint list in to excel. I have created a Custom HTML code providing a user interface to the user where they can choose the report type and some values (filter), and export button clicking on which report will be downloaded (using owssvr.dll).there is no error message, so I am suspecting a limit on view.set_viewFields(viewFields). is it so then what is the solution, or any alternative?

```
//viewFields
var viewFields="";
if (selectedReportType="A")
{
     viewFields=['col1','col2','col3']; 
     //This is working and I can see my view is updated with these viewFields.
}
else
{
     viewFields=['col1','col2','col3'.........'col32'];
     //Not working and columns are not added
}
//Creating a new View
var view = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();  
view.set_title("Reporting");
view.set_viewFields(viewFields);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);

//after view is loaded filter the view based on the values enter by user in //other text boxes.

if(CreatedDateField!="")
query="<Where><FieldRef name='created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>DateValue</Value></Where>";

 view.set_viewQuery(query);
 view.update();
clientContext.load(view)

//redirect to ows.dll with List and View GUID.
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested with the JSOM code below to create view with 32 columns as view fields, all the fields are displaying in the new created view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CreateListView, 'sp.js');

function CreateListView() {
    // You can optionally specify the Site URL here to get the context
    // If you don't specify the URL, the method will get the context of the current site
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("/sites/dev");

    // Get List Object
    var olistCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
    var oList = olistCollection.getByTitle("JSOMView");

    // New "ViewCreationInformation" object
    var creationInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();

    // Code to update the display name for the view.
    creationInfo.set_title("Custom View");

    // If passed "true" this new view will be set as default view of the list
    creationInfo.set_setAsDefaultView("false");

    // You can optionally specify row limit for the view
    creationInfo.set_rowLimit("15");

    // Add all the fields over here with comma separated value as mentioned below
    // You can mention display name or internal name of the column   
    var viewFields = new Array(
           'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8',
           'col9','col10','col11','col12','col13','col14','col15',
           'col16','col17','col18','col19','col20','col21','col22',
           'col23','col24','col25','col26','col27','col28','col29',
           'col30','col31','col32'
     );
    creationInfo.set_viewFields(viewFields);

    // Specify type of the view. Below are the options

    // 1. none - The type of the list view is not specified

    // 2. html - Sspecifies an HTML list view type

    // 3. grid - Specifies a datasheet list view type

    // 4. calendar- Specifies a calendar list view type

    // 5. recurrence - Specifies a list view type that displays recurring events

    // 6. chart - Specifies a chart list view type

    // 7. gantt - Specifies a Gantt chart list view type
    var viewType = new SP.ViewType();
    creationInfo.set_viewTypeKind(viewType.none);

    // You can optionally specify a query as mentioned below.
    // Create one CAML query to filter list view and mention that query below
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title'/></IsNotNull></Where>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    creationInfo.set_query(camlQuery);

    var oListViews = oList.get_views().add(creationInfo);

    //Load the client context and execute the batch
    clientContext.load(oListViews);

    // Execute the query to the server.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onsuccess, onfailed);
}

function onsuccess() {
    console.log('Success');
}

function onfailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

[image]

Reference:

[Create View in SharePoint using JSOM](http://www.codesharepoint.com/jsom/create-view-in-sharepoint-using-jsom)

Comment: Thanks Jerry for the inputs, I have a code where I am deleting the existing columns in the View, based on the report type I am adding new columns, and then trying to download that view. Can I share my code If you can help? In debug mode I am not seeing any error, but when I switch to see my view, the columns are not added. The Code can be easily tested by adding it in to script editor or HTML form web part.

Comment: Hi Moranis, you can create a new list and add col1-col32 as a test, then add the code snippet above in Script Editor web part to see if it works.

Comment: Hello Jerry, I already have a code written for the same. But the code is not working appropriately. Some times it adds up the columns and sometimes not. I am trying to figure out what is happening. Even in Browser debug mode, the cursor goes through adding up all the columns but in actual the columns are not populated.

Comment: @Moranis, as you said the column sometimes added sometimes not, a suggestion is put some fields instead of put all the fields in the array to test side by side. If the field name in array is wrong, then it will show the error message in browser developer tool:  FailedColumn 'co l8' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Comment: No jerry, all the columns names are correct. But the thing is there are some lookup columns some calculated ones. Is there any limit for those?

Comment: Yes, SharePoint limit the max lookup columns count in the view is 12, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/12/02/sharepoint-20102013-list-view-lookup-threshold-uncovered/, maybe this cause only parts of the fields added into the view.